# Data distribution and shared memory

Tags: distribution, shared-memory

Let's say I have a server machine S with a database. There are also other client machines Cx that connect to this server to get a huge quantity of data. These data are then processed according to some business rules, so new data is  produced. On each client machine, there is an application that receives queries at a very high rate and that needs to answer the queries rapidly using the processed data.

I have two questions:

1. What is the best way to transfer the huge quantity of data from S to each client Cx? Note that I also want the data to be in sync with the database. So each time there are changes to the database, I want to transfer the modifications to the client.
2. One application running on the client get the data from S (question 1) and processes it. Then, the query application needs this data to answer requests. How to share the processed data between the two applications? Note that the two applications run on the same machine and that a huge quantity of data has to be shared.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I took the direction of caching. There is one product from Terracotta that is called EHCache.